# inconsistent behavior of static member

Tags: c#, asp.net, static

I have two projects in a solution. A C# class library project encapsulate logic and a asp.net website for view.
Here is the logic:

```
public static class LoginHandler
{
   private static string _connectionString = Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=ASP;Integrated Security=True"
   private static SqlConnection Connection;
   static LoginHandler()
    {
        Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    }
     public static User StudentLogin(string username, string password)
    {
        using (Connection)
        {
         .........
        }
    }
}
```

Everything goes well until I call StudentLogin method for the second time.

I get an InvalidOperationException says that 
the ConnectionString Property of Connection is not initialized.
(ConnectionString is "" through the watch window)

My question is, since static members are initialized only once(this case,in the static constructor), how could the ConnectionString property changed?

Or,is the using statement which calls the IDisposible.Dispose() to be blamed?

Comment: Why do you need `LoginHandler` after all? Define your `SqlConnection` in your method and use using as `using(var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))`.

Answer (score 2):

> Or,is the using statement which calls the IDisposible.Dispose() to be blamed?

Yes. You should create a new connection each time the `StudentLogin` method is called. You don't even need the static field to keep a reference to it.

```
public static User StudentLogin(string username, string password)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. By the way ,will an connection that only closes when  shutting down the website  make better performance than creating a new connection everytime calling the method and close it when the method finshes?

Comment: @Hohenheim Sql connections are pooled, opening and closing them is very cheap. You can read some more on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx